# How do I find the path to genymotion

Tags: intellij, genymotion

I am having a problem trying to find where Ubuntu stores the program folders. I am new to Linux and only know a few limited terminal commands, but I have tried hundreds of folders in Ubuntu and cannot find where the programs reside. I tried the find command but I get a few hundred hits and none of them seem to be correct. I have GenyMotion installed and running correctly but I need the path to the program folder in order to connect it with Intellij.

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks
Clan

Comment: For what I see, Genymotion would be a virtual machine running in VirtualBox. So there is no "Genymotion program". It would be VirtualBox booting a VM from some VDI/VDMK image.

Answer (score 1):

Use the which command to fine the location of the command e.g.:

```
which genymotion
```

If the program is installed in a standard location, it will be found and the location printed out.  If a third party application is not installed in a standard location, then to run it from  the command line you either need to add its location to your PATH variable, or type in the full path, which you may have decided at installation time. For instance, if you decided to install a program to your Documents folder, your program path might look like:

```
/home/<username>/Documents/<myprogram>/bin
```

Comment: I tried the 'which' command but it returns nothing. It seems a shame that I cannot right click on the Genymotion icon in the applications folder and get the path and the actual name of the file it is starting, but that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

In bash use `type` to see what the command is:  alias, built-in, and if not either the path to the executable.

```
>type gcc 
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
>type ll
ll is aliased to `ls -alF'
```

You can add a `realpath` invocation to resolve links (even the multi-stage links used by alternatives`):

```
>type java
java is /usr/bin/java
>realpath /usr/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Comment: bash: type: genymotion: not found

Answer (score 0):

In my installation, and -- by sound of it -- in yours as well, `genymotion` is not in the `PATH` itself and therefore will not be found using commands like `type ...` or `which ...`. Instead, I would try running the following:

```
grep -Pio 'Exec=\K[^\r\n]+' /usr/share/applications/genymobile-genymotion.desktop | xargs -I path dirname "path"
```

Because you said you are new to Linux, I will briefly summarize what that command is doing. Grep is going to run a RegEx match against the  `/usr/share/applications/genymobile-genymotion.desktop` file using a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE) engine (`-P`), which will perform a case-insensitive search (`-i`) and return back only the contents which match the provided expression (`-o`). The pattern to search for is `Exec=[^\r\n]+`, with a `\K` tossed in after the equal-sign so that GREP will only print out the contents after that point. This pattern was chosen because a typical Desktop file will look like the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Genymotion
GenericName=Android Emulator
GenericName[fr]=Emulateur Android
Icon=/opt/genymobile/genymotion/icons/icon.png
Exec=/opt/genymobile/genymotion/genymotion
Categories=Development;Emulator;
```

After GREP matches against that file, all results are "piped" to `xargs`, which is basically just a compatibility wrapper to take multiline outputs and pass each line as an input to another command. (It can do more than that, but such is outside the scope of this answer.) `xargs` then invokes `dirname` for the given path result. `dirname` is just a little Linux program that, when given a file path, splits apart the filename from the rest of the path and then returns back the path/directory portion without the filename.

As can be seen in the screenshot below, in my case, `genymotion` is installed under `/opt/genymobile/genymotion`

[image: Example showing path to Genymotion installation]

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to put genymotion for android studio and "/opt/genymobile/genymotion" path is work for me

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since your question, but I leave this answer for people who have the same problems.
if

> which genymotion

doesn't work for you, most probably this command would be useful

> whereis genymotion

and solves your problem.